# Running a Sonarqube analysis from Gradle

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to run a SonarQube analysis on my project from my build.gradle file. When I do I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to create temp file in ?/.sonar/cache/_tmp
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCache.newTempFile(FileCache.java:138)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCache.get(FileCache.java:83)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.lambda$getScannerEngineFiles$0(JarDownloader.java:60)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:61)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
```

I've tried setting the sonar.path.temp to "/tmp/.sonar", but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there some other setting that I'm missing to make this work?

Comment: can you try with the enivronment varriable `SONAR_HOME` set to `./.sonar` - thois should set this path within your project, and at least you can rule out file permission issues :)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was setting `-Dsonar.userHome='pwd'/.sonar` also changing `SONAR_USER_HOME` may help.